# Catch an exception thrown in Dataset foreachPartition() function on the driver in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, exception, driver, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to find a way to catch an exception thrown by a Spark inside a foreachPartition() method on its driver. When using foreachPartition() on a Dataset, I pass a lambda function that is carried out across the various workers. This process could potentially throw an exception. But I cannot figure out a way to catch this exception on the driver. It appears this is by design. Is there something I can do to change this? Here is an example of what I'm currently doing:

```
public static void driverClassExecute() {
    Dataset<ModelDTO> dataset = getSomeData();
    dataset.foreachPartition(AClass::methodCanThrowException);
    //How can I recover if the above throws an exception?
}
public static void methodCanThrowException(Iterator<ModelDTO> it) throws Exception {
    //do stuff. If bad, throw exception. This crashes the driver.
    throw new Exception("any exception");
}
```

I'm also using Eclipse Oxygen IDE in case the compiler matters.

Comment: Such facility is not available, are you trying to handle exception and avoid job stoppage?

Comment: @AbhishekN Thanks for confirming. And yes, this would be to avoid the job from stopping entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case foreachPartition will throw an exception so you can wrap that call in a try-catch and handle as any other exception, although the spark job will already have failed. To avoid the job failing you would have to handle the exception in methodCanThrowException.

Comment: I don't follow... If I handle the exception in methodCanThrowException(), it won't throw anything. But if I throw something from methodCanThrowException(), the job will fail and the foreachPartition() won't throw an exception (I don't think it can throw one anyway, making a try/catch useless around foreachPartition()). So I'm not sure what you're suggesting?

Comment: If you throw something from methodCanThrowException(), the job will fail and an exception IS thrown from foreachPartition.

Comment: More precisely it will get retried first and if it throws on retry then the job will fail. Do you mean you want to get the exceptions from  tasks that throw but succeed on retry?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure what this "retry" is that you're referring to unless it's something Spark is doing silently. In naive terms, I want to wrap the .foreachPartition() in a try/catch and if an exception is thrown from the method passed as an argument to  .foreachPartion(), catch it instead of having the application just halt immediately. I don't think something like this is possible without rewriting it in Scala.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the difficulty is, perhaps this is what you are looking for: try { dataset.foreachPartition(AClass::methodCanThrowException); } catch (Exception ex) { ... }

Comment: So it turns out this answer is actually 100% correct. It's kind of strange, but I had to wrap the logic using a base Exception class. Any other sub-class resulted in the compiler complaining that the exception was never thrown. This included RuntimeException.

Comment: Yes this is due to a Java Vs Scala mismatch in how exceptions work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be doing things a little differently but a typical execution for Spark partitioned DS would be done in following steps:

1. Create the Dataset ==> This is already done through getSomeData() function.
2. Iterate over partitions using dataset.foreachPartition() ==> keep in mind that this function does not give you single record, it gives you the whole partition which could have many records based on your splitting logic in getSomeData().
3. Next level Iteration through partition.forEachRemaining() to obtain individual records by the executor and run appropriate business logic.

When you run the #3 step, this is where you should pass each record your methodCanThrowException() like in Java -

```
partition.forEachRemaining(record -> {
      try {
        methodCanThrowException(record);
      } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.info(<record-key> "etc for debugging or tracking");
      }
);
```

Obviously you can handle exceptions in several ways to write to audit file for correction etc. But your processing will not fail due to an exception in the processing method.